# Deleting Elements from an Array based on their Position every 3 Elements

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, indices, array-difference

I created an array called `elements_n` which has the elements `0` to `N-1` where `N` is 2. The below numbers are the elements of the array called `elements_n`:

```
0 1
```

I have another array called `Arr` which has the following elements:

```
0 1 3 1 2 4
```

If any of the first 3 elements of the array `Arr` are equal to the first element of `elements_n` which is `0`, I would like to delete that element from the array called `Arr`. I then repeat the same process for the next 3 elements of the array `Arr`. So to explain myself better, I will use the following example:

Compare the first 3 elements of array `Arr` which are 0, 1, 3  to the first element of `elements_n` which is 0. Since `Arr[0] == elements_n[0]`. I delete `Arr[0]` from the array `Arr`.

Compare the next 3 elements of array `Arr` which are 1, 2, 4 to the second element of `elements_n` which is 1. Since `Arr[3] == elements_n[1]`. I delete `Arr[3]` from the array `Arr`. So the elements that should be left in the array `Arr` are:

```
1 3 2 4
```

When I implemented it myself in C programming with the code found below the end result is coming:

```
 1       3       3       2       2       4
```

Rather than:

```
  1       3       2       4
```

This is the code I implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2 

int main() {    
    unsigned *elements_n = malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        elements_n[i] = i; //Created an array which has the elements 0 to N-1
    }
    printf("\n");

    unsigned Arr[6] = { 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4 };
    unsigned position_indices[2] = { 3, 3 };  //Moving every 3 elements in the Arr array. 

    int count = 0; 
    int index = 0;
    unsigned *ptr_Arr = &Arr[0];

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < position_indices[count]; i++) {
            if (ptr_Arr[i] == elements_n[count]) {
                index = i + 1; //Index of the Arr element that has the same value as the element in the array elements_n 

                for (int j = index - 1; j < position_indices[count] - 1; j++) {
                    ptr_Arr[j] = ptr_Arr[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        ptr_Arr += position_indices[count] - 1; 
        count++;
    } while (count < 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", Arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(elements_n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Gerhardh I have to do it that manner because the code is part of another project where the comparison is being done every 3 elements. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "deleting an element from an array"? An array has a fixed number of elements; you cannot add elements to it or remove elements from it. What you *may* do is to store somewhere the number of *useful* elements and manipulate the useful part of the array.

Comment: What role would `position_indices` play in your code.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` You always print all 6 elements. You need to keep track of how many elements you have removed.

Comment: @AlexP sorry for not being clear. What I meant is that I wanted to reduce the elements of Arr which are 0 1 3 1 2 4  to 1 3 2 4 after comparing them as I explained above.

Comment: You only "delete" within a group of 3. All elements that are located in the array after this group are not shifted accordingly.

Comment: @Gerhardh For every iteration in the do while loop, position_indices is just used to move every 3 elements in the array Arr.

Comment: Think of it as copying the whole array but skipping the entries you don't want.

Comment: Yes, but the position withing the overall array does not change when you remove an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of how many elements you removed from the array.
My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t fancy_delete_3(const int elems[], size_t elemssize, int arr[], size_t arrsize)
{
    assert(elems != NULL);
    assert(arr != NULL);
    assert(arrsize%3 == 0);
    assert(elemssize*3 == arrsize);
    // we need to count the removed elements, to know how much we need to shift left
    size_t removed = 0;
    // for each element in elems
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elemssize; ++i) {
        // check the three correponding elements in arr
        for (size_t j = i*3; j < (i+1)*3; ++j) {
            assert(j >= removed);
            const size_t pos = j - removed;
            // if elems[i] matches any of the corresponding element in arr
            if (elems[i] == arr[pos]) {
                // remove element at position pos
                assert(arrsize >= pos + 1);
                // I don't think this can ever overflow
                memmove(&arr[pos], &arr[pos + 1], (arrsize - pos - 1) * sizeof(int));
                ++removed;
                // array is one element shorter, so we can just decrease the array size
                assert(arrsize > 0);
                --arrsize;
            }
        }
    }
    // we return the new size of the array
    return arrsize;
}

#define __arraycount(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])

int main()
{
    int elements_n[] = {0,1};
    int arr[] = {0,1,3, 1,2,4};
    size_t newsize = fancy_delete_3(elements_n, __arraycount(elements_n), arr, __arraycount(arr));

    printf("arr size=%zu {", newsize);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < newsize; ++i)
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
    printf("}\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using memmove() makes this O(n^2). Better to move the elements as you check them.

Comment: Thank you ! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this (not tested).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2 

int main()
{ 
  unsigned *elements_n = malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    elements_n[i] = i; //Created an array which has the elements 0 to N-1
  }

  unsigned Arr[6] = { 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4 };

  int dest_index = 0;
  int src_index = 0;
  int count = sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0]); 

  for ( ; src_index < count; src_index++)
  {
    int group = src_index / 3;
    if (Arr[src_index] != elements_n[group])
    {
      Arr[dest_index++] = Arr[src_index];
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < dest_index; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\t", Arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(elements_n);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several related problems around how you perform deletions.  In the first place, it's not clear that you understand that you cannot actually delete anything from a C array.  The closest you can come is to *overwrite* it with something else.  Often, pseudo-deletion from an array is implemented by moving each of the elements following the deleted one one position forward, and reducing the *logical* length of the array.<sup>*</sup>  You seem to have chosen this alternative, but (problem 1) you miss maintaining or updating a logical array length.

Your problem is made a bit more complicated by the fact that you logically subdivide your array into segments, and you seem not to appreciate that your segments are *variable-length* in that, as described, they shrink when you delete an element.  This follows from the fact that deleting an element from one group does not change the assignments of elements to other groups.  You *do* have a mechanism in `position_groups` that apparently serves to track the sizes of the groups, and in that sense its name seems ill-fitting.  In the same way that you need to track and update the logical length of the overall array, you'll need to track and update the lengths of the groups.

Finally, you appear to have an off-by-one error here:

> ```
>               for (int j = index - 1; j < position_indices[count]-1; j++)
> ```

that would be clearer if `position_indices` were better named (see above), but recognizing that what it actually contains is the *size* of each group, and that `index` and `j` represent indices within the group, it follows that the boundary condition for the iteration should instead be just `j < position_indices[count]`.  That's moot, however, because you're going to need a somewhat different approach here anyway.

Suggestion, then:

1. When you delete an element from a group, move up the entire tail of the array, not just the tail of the group.
2. In service to that, update both group size and logical array size when you perform a deletion, remembering that that affects also where each subsequent group *starts*.
3. When you examine or output the result, remember to disregard array elements past the logical end of the array.

---

<sup>*</sup> "Logical array size" means the number of (leading) elements that contain meaningful data.  In your case, the logical array size is initially the same as the physical array size, but each time you delete an element (and therefore move up the tail) you reduce the logical size by one.

Answer (score 0):

You never really "deleted" any element, you just shifted-down the
second  and third  elements  from each  3-group.  And then,  when
printing, you iterated over the whole array.

Arrays  are just  continuous  blocks  of memory,  so  you need  a
different strategy.  You could  traverse the original  array with
two  indexes, one  as  the  general index  counter  and other  as
the  index  for the  shifted  slot.  If  the current  element  is
different from  the corresponding  `elements_n` item, copy  it to
the secondary index and increase it.

In case nothing is equal to the `elements_n` item, you would just
reassign the  array elements to  themselves. However, as  soon as
one is  equal you  will be  shifting them  with the  advantage of
keeping track of the new size.

Also, calculating the corresponding `elements_n` item is a simple
matter of dividing the current index by 3, so you don't even need
an extra variable to that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 2

int main()
{
    unsigned elements_n[N] = { 0, 1 };
    unsigned Arr[N*3] = { 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4 };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < N*3; i++)
        if (Arr[i] != elements_n[i/3])
            Arr[j++] = Arr[i];

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        printf(" %d", Arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```